# State Variable not being correctly captured, when passing through components

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have excluded some parts of my original code for readability, sorry if it causes any confusion!

> I have a state variable in `App.js` defined as such
>
> ```html
> const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])
> ```

---

> From `App.js`, I pass into `Tasks.js` the state variable as a
> prop.
> `Tasks.js` receives the prop and sorts it as below (when a certain button is clicked)
>
> ```js
> const Tasks = function ({tasks, setTasks}) {
>         setTasks(tasks.sort((a, b) => {
>             if ((moment(a.isoDay).unix()) < (moment(b.isoDay).unix())) return -1
>             else {
>                 return 0
>             }
>         }))
>     }
> ```

---

> This causes the state variable in `App.js` to be updated, and this state variable is
> passed into `Calendar.js` (from `App.js`) as a prop as well, as seen below
>
> ```js
> const Calendar = ({tasks}) => {
>     function TaskToCalendar(tasks) {
>         console.log(tasks)
>         console.log(tasks[0])
>     }
> }
> ```

However, I am not accurately capturing the value of tasks.

> For example, `console.log(tasks)` yields this **before** it is
> sorted in `Tasks.js`
>
> ```html
> (2) [{…}, {…}]
> 0: {text: "Test0", day: "Tue Jun 01 2021"}
> 1: {text: "Test1", day: "Wed Jun 02 2021"}
> ```
>
> and yields this **after** it is sorted in `Tasks.js`
>
> ```html
> (2) [{…}, {…}]
> 0: {text: "Test1", day: "Wed Jun 02 2021}
> 1: {text: "Test0", day: "Tue Jun 01 2021}
> ```

---

> But, `console.log(tasks[0])` yields this **before** and
> **after** it is sorted
>
> ```html
> {text: "Test0", day: "Tue Jun 01 2021"}
> ```

I have to click on another button somewhere in my UI (that runs an unrelated function), for `console.log(tasks[0])` to yield `{text: "Test1", day: "Wed Jun 02 2021}` **after** sorting.

How would I go about correctly passing the value of `tasks`, such that accessing the array indices gives me the correct values?

Comment: I'd first try doing a non-destructive sort to avoid manipulating state directly.

Comment: Passing useState down like that makes me twitch a little. I'd much rather pass down a function to update state into that component instead, or use context/provider. It's not wrong, but it doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SetTask function is working asynchronously. hence, this behavior.
For logging the value you can use the useeffect Hook

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that setTask was asynchronous. The useEffect hook worked perfectly!